# Отследить вызов CoCreateInstance() и получить аргументы

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi

в библиотеке ole32.dll есть функция CoCreateInstance(), как отследить ее вызов и получить (по возможности) аргументы самого вызова? Инжектировать dll в процесс - не подходит, т.к. и другие процессы могут использовать функцию.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: @gbg не совсем верно, я наглядно указал что способ инжектирования не подходит и нужно другое решение

Comment: Проблема в том, что в зависимости от реально решаемой вами задачи, само решение может довольно таки сильно меняться - например, если у вас есть исходники того OLE-объекта, который вы отлаживаете, это одно решение, если их нет - это другое решение

Ну и никто не мешает в иньектированной DLL логировтаь PID процесса, который создает экземпляр.